# AWS の Parameter Store と Secrets Manager はどのように使い分けますか？

Tags: aws

AWS で秘匿値を扱う方法には、[AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) と [AWS Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/secrets-manager/) のふたつがあると知りました。

この両者はどのように違い、どのように使い分けるべきなのでしょうか？　たとえば次のようなことを気にしています。

- 想定用途や使われ方に違いはありますか？
- 性能に違いはありますか？
- API でできることに大きな違いはありますか？
- 他の AWS サービスとの連携に特筆すべき違いはありますか？
- 料金に大きな違いはありますか？

詳細に書くと長くなりそうなので、特徴的な部分を教えていただきつつ、残りはドキュメント等にリンクしていただければ嬉しいです。

Answer (score 1):

Systems Manager の FAQ と双方の課金体系ドキュメントを読みました。

ざっくりとした理解ですが、私が重要そうだと思った違いは以下の 2 点です：

- Parameter Store のスタンダードタイプは追加料金無しで利用できる。
- Secret Manger では秘匿値のローテーションとデータベース統合ができる。

以下ドキュメントからの引用です。

https://aws.amazon.com/jp/systems-manager/faq/

> AWS シークレットマネージャーは、ローテーション、監査、アクセスコントロールと言った組織でのシークレットのライフサイクルを中央で管理するためのサービスです。シークレットマネージャーを使うと、シークレットを自動的にローテーションできるようになるので、セキュリティとコンプライアンスの要件を満たすのに役立ちます。シークレットマネージャーは MySQL、PostgreSQL、Amazon Aurora on Amazon RDS への統合を組み込むことができ、これは Lambda 関数のカスタマイズで他のタイプのシークレットにも拡張できます。
>
> AWS Systems Manager パラメータストアには、設定データ管理のためのセキュアで、階層的なストレージがあり、これにはシークレットも含みます。データベース接続タイプ、文字れる、パスワードとライセンスコードはパラメータ値として保存され、監査とアクセスコントロールが可能です。保存された値はプレーンテキストでも暗号化されたデータでも構いません。値はパラメータ固有の名前で参照できます。システムマネージャーパラメータを参照してジェネリック設定と自動化スクリプトを構築して、Amazon ECS や AWS CloudFormation など様々な AWS サービスにわたって使用できます。

https://aws.amazon.com/jp/systems-manager/pricing/

> AWS Systems Manager パラメータストアはスタンダードパラメータとアドバンスドパラメータで構成されています。スタンダードパラメータは追加料金なしでご利用いただけます。

https://aws.amazon.com/jp/secrets-manager/pricing/

> Secrets Manager の料金は、保存するシークレットの数と、使用する API コールの数に基づきます。